# IE 9 asks two times what I want to do with the file

Tags: internet-explorer, popups, dynamics-crm

When I want to open a docx. file from dynamics 365 I get the message "what do you want to do with the file?" Immediately after I press "save as", there opens a second pop-up with the same question "What do you want to do with the file?". No matter what answer I click in the second pop-up, it dissapears and I only 1 have document open.

The second pop up is useless and doesn't do anything but it's very annoying that I have to click a second pop-up for nothing.

I tried to uncheck "always ask before opening this type of file" but it didn't help. I don't think it's a dynamics 365 thing because the pop-up is triggered in IE.

Has someone experienced the same or does someone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a recent version of Dynamics then IE 9 is no longer supported or recommended.

[Web application requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/web-application-requirements)

> Although you may be able to use Internet Explorer 8, Internet Explorer
>   9, or an Internet Explorer and Windows combination that is not
>   supported in the previous table, those web browsers are not
>   recommended and are not supported with this version of Dynamics 365
>   for Customer Engagement apps.

You are probably better off upgrading to a more recent browser version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! is this also the case for IE 11?

Comment: @FouadKada Depends check the link.